# get_body_params() is always empty in POST request

Tags: php, array, api, json

I am registering a custom route like this :

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route( 'professeurEQ', 'statistics', array(
          'methods'  => 'POST',
          'callback' => 'test_proeq_post',
      ));
});
```

The callback is written like this :

```
function test_proeq_post($request) {
  $jsonParams = $request->get_body_params();
  return var_dump($jsonParams);
}
```

I am sending the POST request using Postman and the following body :

```
{
    "userID" = 3
}
```

Whatever I am doing, the $jsonParams is always empty. The same thing happens with methods like get_json_params or get_params or get_param.

get_body() works, but I would like to receive an array and use the get_body_params() method.

If I do

```
var_dump($request)
```

Then I see the full request, and I noticed all the parameters are *protected*. I think it must be the cause of the problem, but how to solve it ?

Comment: What does `get_body()` return? Have you set `Content-Type` to `application/json`? In Postman you need to select raw for the body and select JSON from the dropdown.

Comment: @JacobPeattie get_body() returns 
```array (size=0)   empty```

In Postman I have selected RAW for the body and JSON in the dropdown (there was a mistake here initially but after correcting it, I get the same result. But thanks for this already).

How to set Content-type ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value you're trying to send in the body is not valid JSON:

```
{
    "userID" = 3
}
```

JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "userID": 3
}
```

Comment: indeed! thanks !